# How to change path that @schematics/angular uses to generate component

Tags: angular-console

When trying to generate a component via angular console using @schematics/angular:component, this is the path it attempts to use:

`/apps/client/src/app/modules/app/app.module.ts`.

I used `modules/app/app.module.ts` as the value for `declaring NgModule` so it could find the right one.

It basically took this path and added it to `/apps/client/src/app`, which is not correct. I rearranged my project structure a bit so that this is now the correct path:

`/apps/client/src/modules/app/app.module.ts`.

I.e., I removed `app` after `src`.

Is there a way to adjust the path somewhere? Or is this just the schematic and it cannot be changed without a fork? The intent is to remove the first `app` in the path.